# Getting an invalid byte sequence error in utf-8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium-webdriver, utf-8, cucumber

I am getting an error on my feature file even though I do not have any special character there. And I have entered the encoder, `# encoding: UTF-8` on the top.

Any suggestions?

```
*invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)
./features/step_definitions/common_step.rb:344:in `gsub'
./features/step_definitions/common_step.rb:344:in `/^I should see sometext "(.*?)"$/'
```

And this is my step definition:

```
Then(/^I see toaster message "(.*?)"$/) do |message|
  sleep(5)
  puts error_message.text
  expect(error_message.text.gsub("\n",' ')).to eq message
end
```

Comment: What is the string value of `error_message.text`?

Comment: This is the method for that:                                                                         class ErrorMessage 
  def initialize(driver)
    @driver = driver
  end

def text
 @driver.find_element(:css, "div.notification-bar.slide-up").text

end
end. It equates to any pop up message on the page. But for some reason its failing

Comment: I'm curious about the value of `error_message.text`.  If you're calling `gsub` on that string and it throws an error, it will help to know the value.

Comment: Then I see toaster message "To save you money, we've upgraded your pack from Silver to Platinum, which gives you the same great reward for less." This is my feature file step and this is what I am expecting the step definition to match